Getting Visual studio Code to run C++
enter image description here Visual studio code does not give me the option to run this beginner program in C++
In the drop down menu on the right side of the screen shot i should have an option to RUN the beginner program. But [enter image description here] (https://i.sstatic.net/IV5in.png)
But when i try to run the program, i do not know what to do at this point.

Choose cl.exe. If there are any errors, upload that image as well
